# Prove alternating group has half of the size of symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove: For $n>1$, $A_n$ has order $\frac{n!}{2}$.

The textbook writes the proof as follows:

> For each odd permutation $\alpha$, the permutation $(12)\alpha$ is even and, by the cancellation property in groups, $(12)\alpha \neq (12)\beta$,when $\alpha \neq \beta$. Thus, there are at least as many even permutations as there are odd ones.$\dots$

However, I don't understand why "$(12)\alpha \neq (12)\beta$ when $\alpha \neq \beta$" implies that there are at least as many even permutations as there are odd ones.

Comment: The proof basically maps each odd permutation to a unique even permutation, putting them into a one-to-one correspondence. Therefore the number of even and odd permutations are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are odd permutations. Thus the statement says that for every pair of distinct odd permutations $\{ \alpha, \beta \}$, you can find an associated distinct pair of even permutations, namely $\{(12) \alpha, (12) \beta\}$. Therefore, the number of even permutations is greater than or equal to the number of odd permutations.

Comment: So you can also find another associated distinct pair of even permutations $\{(3 4)\alpha,(3 4)\beta \}$. Is that right?

Comment: You don't want to use $(34)$ because it is only assumed $n>1$.